# Receive 2394 in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why am I getting the error?

I tried various methods, but I did not get the result and this error was not fixed

**my code:**

```
function $sum(xor:string[]):string
function $sum(xor:number[]):number
{
    let xor_;
    if(xor instanceof String){
        for(let i of xor){
            xor_+=i;
        }
    }else{
        for(let i of xor){
            xor_+=i;
        }
    }
    return xor_;
}
```

**my error:**

[image: error]

Comment: Please add the error as _text_, as per [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: But...string and number are not the same thing. It's not clear what you were expecting?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads; the final function, the *actual* implementation, needs to have a signature that's compatible with all its overloads.

Comment: Also, `xor` will never be `instanceof String`. It's an *array*. Dealing with that will be tricky if empty arrays are allowed -- what should the function return? It can't return `0` or `""`, the implementation won't know which it should provide. Throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error mentions, you must provide a valid implementation signature:
Info from the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

[Stackblitz example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEgM4gLYAoAecBOAXKlPjGAOYDaAugJTGnkUDcAsAFCiSwIrrY8RMJgBGAU3y0GIjBPzsu4aPCRpMuAoQCC%20fAEMAngB4SZSogA%20iWfIB8MsZKuIzzTgG9OiH4gA24lCIQgD6hIj6YIaKvogwwJr4cWAkkRDicMCIAMpMlHReHLGxwARYAUEwiJnBBAXexY2hANQAvDAxjYgAvg0%203eJ%20qOKFXYil%20OWBcdVZQvVFY74t7Z2NvYv9fYj4gSD4SKGK3UA):

```js
function $sum(xor:string[]):string;
function $sum(xor:number[]):number;
function $sum(xor:Array<string | number>):number | string
{
  /**
   * as per your overloads the function must return 
   * - a string when the input is a string array
   * - a number when the input is a number array
   * 
   * To determine if the input is an array of string or an array of number
   * you could check the type of the first array item
   * i.e. typeof xor[0] === 'string'
   * 
   * as T.J.Crowder pointed out in a comment, 
   * this is not possible when you get an empty array: so your 
   * function must not allow empty arrays: i.e. throw an error
   */
}
```

the first 2 lines are the overloads, the 3rd is the implementation signature.